# Sending Large files using TCP

Tags: sockets, tcp

My client program needs to send a large file to the server program. After the client connects to the server and the server accepts it, the clients specifies the name of the file which it would be sending. Now, the client needs to send the file using TCP.

I know that if the size of the file is small (less than 1k bytes?), I can send it directly using a single call to the "send" function in socket programming. However, does the same work if my file size is large, say about 100 MB? I want to know does "send" by itself handle the task of breaking the large data into packets and sending them reliably or should I be the one handling this?

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't specified a language, or a platform/OS, or much of anything.

Comment: You must *always* look at the return value of the send() call to see how many bytes of data it *actually* read out of your array and placed into the socket's outgoing-data buffer.  This is just as true for "small" amounts of data as large amounts (but the fact that people seem to get away with not doing so sometimes makes them believe otherwise).   Based on the value returned by send() you'll then need to determine what to do next (e.g. call send() again with updated arguments to send more data, or error out, or if all bytes have been sent, return success)

Comment: It is using C. It has a function called send in its socket programming module.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying something similar & My client code looks like this

```
static void send_file(char *ipAddress, char *filename)
{
        struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
        int skt;
        uint32_t addr_size;
        uint32_t sz;
        int32_t sent_bytes;
        FILE *fp;

        if ( inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress, &(serverAddr.sin_addr)) ){
                skt = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
                serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        }
        else {
                inet_pton(AF_INET6, ipAddress, &(serverAddr.sin_addr));
                skt = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
                serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET6;
        }

        serverAddr.sin_port = htons(7891);

        memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr.sin_zero));

        addr_size = sizeof(serverAddr);
        connect(skt, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, addr_size);

        /*find file size*/
        fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
        sz = ftell(fp);
        rewind(fp);

        sent_bytes = send(skt, fp, sz, 0);
        printf("sent %d bytes\n", sent_bytes);
        fclose(fp);
}
```